# Mockito not mocking

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am new to Mockito and trying to mock a service method. However, Mockito is not able to mock the function correctly.

Here is part of the test code:

```
@Mock
ConditionalLimitDao conditionalLimitDao;

@InjectMocks
ConditionalLimitFilingServiceImpl conditionalLimitFilingService;

Mockito.when(conditionalLimitDao.getAllConditionalLimitProductGroups()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(clpg1));
```

The class:

```
public class ConditionalLimitFilingServiceImpl implements ConditionalLimitFilingService {

    @Inject
    private ConditionalLimitDao conditionalLimitDao;

    @Override
    public List<ConditionalLimitFiling> getConditionalLimitFiling(String filingMonth, Date reportDate)
            throws SQLException, RemoteException {

        conditionalLimitProductGroups = getConditionalLimitProductGroups();

        return something;
    }

    private List<ConditionalLimitProductGroup> getConditionalLimitProductGroups() {
        return conditionalLimitDao.getAllConditionalLimitProductGroups();
    }
}
```

I am expecting `getAllConditionalLimitProductGroups()` to return a non-empty list. However, it's returning an empty list. Can anyone help?

Comment: the fact it is returning an empty list and not null shows it is mocking, is clpg1 an  empty array?

Comment: No. it's not empty.  clpg1 is an object of type ConditionalLimitProductGroup.

Comment: what does Arrays.asList(clpg1) return by itself?

Comment: Try the test after you have removed the @Inject. This way you can ensure that the mocked object is not overriden by whoever handles the injection (Assuming your tests runs in a context where injection is enabled).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are forgetting to add this line

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

This line of code should be placed in a `@Before` method to initialize mocks for every test.

Comment: Using the Runner / Extension should provide the same, but that might depend on the JUnit & Mockito Version